# Python, matplotlib, wxpython - Anyway to move an canvas from one frame to another?

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, wxpython

So I don't really have any code to show as it's a very large script I have currently. Having said that I will try and add a simple example shortly.

Basically lets say I have two frames in wxpython, each containing a single panel with a matplotlib canvas. Lets call these canvases graph1 and graph2.

So I know how to plot directly into graph1, using standard methods.

I was wondering if there is any way I could change the location of graph1 into that of graph2, i.e. move the plot to the second frame (window).

Basically I am trying to implement a full screen option for the user, which upon clicking a graph will maximise it into the second frame. I am hoping I can do this just by changing the references rather than re-drawing etc. as I want it to keep the original state of the graph when it maximises.

Comment: If it can be done, it will be very tricky and require touching many parts of the matplotlib internals.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what about if I was to just show a second copy of the graph? Would this be any easier? I assume not...

Comment: The problem is that artists know what axis they belong to which knows what figure it belongs to which knows which canvas object it uses (the canvas object is how it talks to wX).  Thinking about this a bit more, if you can move Wx widgets between frames, you _might_ be able to get this to work, but I don't know enough wx to help.

Comment: Take a look at the wx.Window.Reparent method.